# open IE browser by default

Tags: javascript, html

I created a web site where I would like to have 1 of the button of my menu navigation to open the internet explorer browser. Since the URL I am pointing for this specific button can only be view with IE and not with Chrome, Firefox etc... Which mean if someone is using Chrome for example and want to access this specific link by clicking on it it will open IE browser and see the content.  This is feasible?  thanks in advance

Comment: How can you even know if they have IE installed?

Comment: How annoying would that be! The only solution is to make it compatible with Chrome and Firefox. Why not do that?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not feasible.

Opening in another browser is totally user side. You would have to alert the user that this page is best viewed in Internet Explorer and leave it up to them to download/open Internet Explorer to view it.

Comment: And, you should note ie sucks :)

Comment: Yeah. Never mind the fact that no one should be making an IE only site. >_<